# tinyMCE seems not always to be initialised

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I have set up `tinyMCE` editor to set the content once it has been initialised, I am using `init_instance_callback` to call a function with that purpose. The problem is that the function is called sometimes. I have realised that if I disable cache in the browser through the developer tools, the function is always called otherwise it is called only sometimes. How can I force `tinyMCE` to be always initialised and to call `init_instance_callback` if I visit the same page multiple times.

This is my code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        selector: 'textarea.mceEditor', 
        plugins: 'powerpaste code textcolor link emoticons table print preview visualchars',
        powerpaste_word_import: 'prompt',
        powerpaste_html_import: 'prompt',
        powerpaste_allow_local_images: true,
        browser_spellcheck: true,
        fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
        forced_root_block: false,
        toolbar1: 'forecolor backcolor undo redo styleselect bold italic alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify bullist numlist outdent indent',
        toolbar2: 'link fontsizeselect',
        paste_preprocess : function(pl, o) {
            o.content = o.content.replace(/(<\/p>)/gi,'<br/><br/>');
            o.content = o.content.replace(/(<p>)/gi,'');

        },
        init_instance_callback : "initAdvertDescription"

    });


function initAdvertDescription() {   

        console.log(advertDescription);
        tinyMCE.get(aspnetPrefix_Hash + "tbxDescription").setContent(advertDescription);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** (edited my answer, I didn't know `init_instance_callback` was also part of API v4)

You could instead use the `init` event which as said [in the documentation](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.init)

> Fires after the editor has been initialized. This is after the editor has been filled with contents.

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    setup: function(editor) {
        editor.on('init', function(e) {
            console.log('init event', e);
            editor.setContent(advertDescription);
        });
    }
});
```

TinyMCE documentation is a real mess and not easy at all to find information you want. Moreover APIs version 3 is much better referenced by Google than version 4. Always be careful what version of the documentation you are reading, there have been lots of changes between these two versions.

I personally prefer to use [this URL](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/events/#init) for a clearer documentation.